# replace string in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, replace, find

i have 500 records in a table. one column holds all html data. so e.g -
html>  body> ... /body> /html>.
What i want to do is a find and replace. i have this tag in every single record -
`<table id="something something" />`
i want to replace that in all the rows with `<table id="" />`
now the difficult part is all the "something something" is different for each and every alt. 
So the only common tag is "table id=". how can do a find an replace here?

Comment: What are you trying to replace it with? I think tags didn't let your post come out correctly.

Comment: Yeah, I edited to make the tags show up.

Comment: sorry bout the tags, this website wasnt letting me submit with those tage. anywyas, im using sql server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this (assumes only one "table id" occurs in each):

```
declare @TestTable table (
    html_data varchar(100)
)

insert into @TestTable
    (html_data)
    select '<html><body><table id="something something" /></body></html>'
    union all
    select '<html><body><table id="something different" /></body></html>'

select html_data from @TestTable

update t
    set html_data = LEFT(t.html_data, CHARINDEX('<table id="', t.html_data)-1) 
                    + '<table id="" />'
                    + RIGHT(t.html_data, LEN(t.html_data) - CHARINDEX(' />', t.html_data, CHARINDEX('<table id="', t.html_data)) - 2)
        from @TestTable t

select html_data from @TestTable
```

**EDIT**: Based on feedback in the comments below, this modified code should work.

```
declare @TestTable table (
    html_data varchar(100)
)

insert into @TestTable
    (html_data)
    select '<html><body><table id="xxx"><tr><td></td></tr></table>... </body></html>'

select html_data from @TestTable

update t
    set html_data = LEFT(t.html_data, CHARINDEX('<table id="', t.html_data)-1) 
                    + '<table id="">'
                    + right(t.html_data, LEN(t.html_data) - CHARINDEX('>', t.html_data, CHARINDEX('<table id="', t.html_data)))
        from @TestTable t

select html_data from @TestTable
```

Comment: it added a "<table id="">" before the existing "<table id="eded">" looks good so far but how do i remove existing or replace existing?

Comment: Can you post the html string you're testing against?

Comment: <html><body><table id="xxx"><tr><td></td></tr></table>... more tables and tr's and td's. </body></html>. 
so this is 1 row in the field html of the table in sql server. i hope that answers. thanks for all the help

Comment: This is substantially different than what you originally posted `<table id="something something" />`. The code I wrote was dependent on the existence of the terminating `/>` and will not work in light of this data.

Comment: I've added a second code block to my answer that should handle the case you've posted in your comment.

Comment: perfect. man you're good. thank you so much. for some reason its not letting me pick top answer

Answer (score 4):

Use the [REPLACE function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx):

```
UPDATE YOUR_TABLE
   SET html_data = REPLACE(html_data, 
                           '<table id="something something" />', 
                           '<table id="" />')
```

> the difficult part is all the "something something" is different for each and every alt.

SQL Server 2005+ has CLR functionality, which you'd need to use to create a regex replace function in order to be more accommodating as a single query.  See [this page for both a downloadable script, and the source code](http://www.mssqlclr.com/?page_id=27).

For SQL Server versions prior to that, you might just be better off getting the content to a text file & updating the content via regex/etc, for overwriting the existing content.

Comment: The OP is looking for a generic solution where the table id may be different in each case.

Comment: Yep. It didn't when I made that comment -- and I've replaced my downvote with an upvote.

Comment: JacobM: Have patience :)  I appreciate the reversal

Answer (score 1):

If you write a cursor function to go through each row of the table (very inefficient, but I'm guessing that you're only doing this once?)

Then do a replace on that string:

```
SELECT REPLACE(@HTMLText,'table id="%" />','table id=""');
```

I think that should do what you need, and here is basic cursor functionality if you need it:
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/01/01/sql-server-simple-example-of-cursor/

**EDIT:
Actually, I tested a bit more, and I can't get it to accept the wildcard, although it doesn't complain, I don't see it functioning properly...**

Comment: i like this idea but for some reason nothing happened. it came back with the existing row that was before replace.

Comment: this is my syntax -
select REPLACE(html,'table id="%" />','table id=""') from Articles
where id=101.. html is name of the field.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sorry, I thought I had the wildcard working, but unfortunately the REPLACE() function does not take a wildcard...

Answer (score 0):

You will likely need to write a stored procedure to do this, a combination of a SELECT statement to find and an UPDATE statement to replace.

Comment: logically i know how to do it. anyone knows. do u have an example of the syntax i need to use? if not, please dont answer this question